# EditText: how to remove "null" string obtained from a Json

Tags: android, json, android-edittext

Is there any way I can eliminate the "null" string of an editing text brought from a JSONObject response? and just show the empty EditText.

He did it in the following way.

```
 if (jsonResponse.getString(DataManager.Name).equals("null"){
    edtName.setText("");
 }else{

  edtName.setText(jsonResponse.getString(usersDataInfo.getNombre()));

 }
```

But when the field comes with information, it enters the instruction again and removes the information.

JSON

```
{
    "ID": 23,
    "NOMBRE": null,
    "APELLIDOPATERNO": null,
    "APELLIDOMATERNO": null,
    "TELEFONO": null,
    "CELULAR": null,
    "NACIMIENTO": null,
    "SEXO": null,
    "USUARIOID": 7
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your Json please?

Comment: `{
    "ID": 23,
    "NOMBRE": null,
    "APELLIDOPATERNO": null,
    "APELLIDOMATERNO": null,
    "TELEFONO": null,
    "CELULAR": null,
    "NACIMIENTO": null,
    "SEXO": null,
    "USUARIOID": 7
}`

Comment: I added an answer :)

Comment: I would suggest to use Gson or something similar for parsing between json and objects. then you can do a null check on object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the method isNull() to check for null value.

i.e:

```
if (jsonResponse.isNull("NOMBRE")) {
  edtName.setText("")
} else {
  edtName.setText(jsonResponse.getString("NOMBRE"))
}
```

or in case your returning someting, simply:

```
jsonResponse.isNull("CELULAR") ? (return someting) : (return another thing)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created a sample and for me it's working, take a look :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText etEjemplo;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etEjemplo = findViewById(R.id.etEjemplo);

        String json = "{\n" +
                "\t\"ID\": 23,\n" +
                "\t\"NOMBRE\": null,\n" +
                "\t\"APELLIDOPATERNO\": null,\n" +
                "\t\"APELLIDOMATERNO\": null,\n" +
                "\t\"TELEFONO\": null,\n" +
                "\t\"CELULAR\": null,\n" +
                "\t\"NACIMIENTO\": null,\n" +
                "\t\"SEXO\": null,\n" +
                "\t\"USUARIOID\": 7\n" +
                "}";

        try {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            String nombre = jObj.getString("NOMBRE");
            //You can use jObj.isNull("NOMBRE") instead
            if(nombre.equals("null")){
                etEjemplo.setText("");
            }
            else{
                etEjemplo.setText(nombre);
            }
            //One line case 
            //etEjemplo.setText(nombre.equals("null") ? "" : nombre);
            //or
            //etEjemplo.setText(jObj.isNull("NOMBRE") ? "" : nombre);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```